# How do I search a datetime range in servicenow with getRecords using suds?

Tags: python, wsdl, suds, servicenow

I'm trying to do a Service Now query using suds, but I can't figure out how to specify a date range. Here is my code, it works for returning a record with an exact date:

```
from suds.client import Client

URL = 'https://blah.service-now.com/change_request.do?WSDL'
USERNAME = "blah"
PASSWORD = "blah"

client = Client(URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
result = client.service.getRecords(start_date = "2015-02-03 12:00:00")

print result
```

The printed result gives me a single record matching that exact datetime.

When I try start_date >= or start_date => or start_date >, they all say either "invalid syntax" or "NameError: name 'start_date' is not defined".

How do I "getRecords" for a time range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind the fact that you're basically just using suds to construct SOAP payloads. It helps to take step back and determine the SOAP request needed to get the response you're looking for.

According to the WSDL, the start_date field accepts a single parameter, and behaves like blah=foo, so there's no way to specify ranges *in that parameter*:

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="start_date" type="xsd:string"/>
```

What you probably want is the special "__encoded_query" parameter which accepts an encoded query string that you can construct using the filter builder UI in the ServiceNow web app:

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="__encoded_query" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Let's say you want to query for all change_request records that have a start date within the month of October 2014. Go to the target ServiceNow instance (or any one, really, since the encoded query is going to be the same), and build your filter on /change_request_list.do:
[image: filter UI]

Now, right-click that blue filter and select "Copy query" to get the encoded query:
[image]

Here's the encoded query I generated:

```
start_dateBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2014-10-01','00:00:00')@javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2014-10-31','23:59:59')
```

Now, pass that as your `__encoded_query` parameter, with a payload that looks like this:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <getRecords xmlns="http://www.service-now.com/change_request">
            <__encoded_query xmlns="">start_dateBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2014-10-01','00:00:00')@javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2014-10-31','23:59:59')</__encoded_query>
        </getRecords>
    </Body> 
 </Envelope>
```

So, to make suds work, just replace your `start_date` query with an `__encoded_query` query:

```
from suds.client import Client

URL = 'http://localhost:8080/change_request.do?WSDL'
USERNAME = "admin"
PASSWORD = "admin"

client = Client(URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
result = client.service.getRecords(__encoded_query = "start_dateBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2014-10-01','00:00:00')@javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2014-10-31','23:59:59')")

print result
```

Comment: In case it isn't totally clear, too, ANYTHING you can build in that filter UI and generate an encoded query for can be passed as that `__encoded_query` parameter, including more complex -OR- queries, BUT you may have to consider XML encoding for special XML characters that *aren't* also special URL characters (e.g. <, >)

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed response... But this solution doesn't work. When I used the __encoded_query, it seemed to return "everything". I can reduce the range to less than a minute and I still get 250 results (which seems to be the cap).

Comment: I just found out that SUDS doesn't like anything with an _ in front of it...
https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/330

Comment: Just to let you know, your response was still super helpful. I tried using SOAPpy and it didn't have the _ bug that SUDS has. When I ran the __encoded_query in SOAPpy it worked fine. :D Thanks for your help!